# URL Mapping for Digital Assets in AEM

Tags: aem, sling, url-mapping

I want to give URL mappings to DAM/Digital Assets of My sites. Especially for PDFs. Whenever I give a Download link to PDF it's Showing the full folder structure to the PDF. I want to shorten this. 
I am Using AEM 6.2 .

Comment: I’ve done this before by means of exposing the asset UUID and handling the download via a servlet. So, on author side, the authors adds an asset, then in a sling model, get the UUID and render the servlet path and uuid as a param. Aforementioned servlet would find that asset via the UUID and serve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the mapping in Sling resource resolver factory configuration

```
1. Go to system config manager and search for Sling resource resolver factory.
2. Add new entry "/content/dam/you-project-structure/>/" and "/content/dam/you-project-structure/</"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define URL mappings under the `/etc/map` location.  Take a look at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html, which includes this example:
[image]

Under /etc/map you can create a folder, and then within that folder create a .content.xml file that contains properties such as these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="sling:Mapping"
          sling:internalRedirect="/content/dam/the/full/path/to/your/file.pdf"
          sling:match=".+/content/short-url.pdf"/>
```